# VIM search term loading even after clearing last used search term

Tags: vim

I think that this is a pretty simple problem but I'm not a vim wizard yet so I'm not sure how to get this to stop.

I was editing some code to comment it out so I was typing `i#`<kbd>Esc</kbd> and then `j` to move down to the next line to repeat the same pattern.  I got to a line with an echo in it and for some reason when I hit the key combination, all of the "echo" commands got highlighted and it jumped down to the last occurrence of "echo" in the file.  I must have accidentally hit a bad key combination but I don't know what it was.

I entered `:let @/ = ""` to clear the search pattern and that got rid of the highlighting.  However, every time I open vim back up it's highlighting "echo".  Even if I clear the search pattern it still comes back every time I open vim.  Can anybody help me figure out if there is there some way to get this to stop?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to know.  First, to disable that highlighting in your *current* Vim session, until your next search:

```
:noh
```

If you've done this before you exit Vim, it shouldn't restore the highlighting, but you can also always prevent Vim from re-enabling it the next time you start it by putting this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:set viminfo+=h
```

The reason you got the `echo` highlighted was that you probably typed a <kbd>#</kbd> without pressing <kbd>i</kbd> first.

See:

```
:help :noh
:help 'viminfo'
:help 'hlsearch'
:help #
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the tip about why `echo` is getting highlighted.  That makes a lot of sense.  Re: turning off the highlighting, I've read about `:noh` before but I've also read before that `let @/ = ""` is a "better" way of getting the highlighting to clear since it clears the last used search pattern.  I'm not doubting what you're saying at all.  Just trying to learn/figure out if one way or the other is "better" or not or if there are some circumstances where I'd use one over the other so that I can know which one to use in the future.